# Get variables fom a txtor php file

Tags: php, flash

I have this code on .fla file

> ```
> fm_button.visible = false;
>
> var menu_label:Array = new Array("Introduction", "Products",  "Services", 
>                                "Testimonials", "Our Company", "Contact Us");
>
> var total:Number = menu_label.length;
> var i:Number = 0;
> var page:Number;
> var main_menu:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
> stage.addChild(main_menu);
>
> for (i = 0; i < total; i++)
> {
>   var btn = new flashmo_button();
>   btn.name = "btn" + i;
>   btn.x = fm_button.x;
>   btn.y = fm_button.y + i * ( fm_button.height + 10 );
>   btn.buttonMode = true;
>   btn.item_no = i;
>   btn.flashmo_click_area.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, btn_enter );
>
>   var each_substring:Array = menu_label[i].split("|");
>   btn.flashmo_button_label.fm_label.text = each_substring[0];
>   btn.item_url = each_substring[1];
>   main_menu.addChild(btn);
> }
>
> function btn_over(e:MouseEvent):void
> {
>   e.target.parent.over = true;
> }
>
> function btn_out(e:MouseEvent):void
> {
>   e.target.parent.over = false;
> }
> ```

What i want is to get this values:

> ("Introduction", "Products",  "Services", "Testimonials", "Our
>   Company", "Contact Us");

from a text or php file named menu.php or menu.txt

Is this possible?

Comment: really not sure what you are asking.

Comment: var menu_label:Array = new Array("Introduction", "Products",  "Services", 
                               "Testimonials", "Our Company", "Contact Us"); these values ​​to be obtained from a file .txt or .php

Comment: var menu_label:Array = new Array("get_names from menu.php");  now you understand?

Answer (score 0):

Why you need read from .php file?

Is this client-server communication?
In that case, when .fla file loads by client browser over http(s) you should do something like this:

menu.php (for example put this file to document root folder):

```
<?php $menu = array('Elem1', 'Elem2');
echo json_encode($menu); ?>
```

.fla:

```
var sendData:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest('/menu.php');
request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(request);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleted);
```

So, your .fla are doing query to server and get's list of categories (onCompleted method receive data).

If this is not server-client communication, you should use other file format, because .php is not a data storage )